# Set the next row of kendo grid programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have kendo grid and a button. On button click I want to change the grid content from currently selected row to the next row.

- How can I achieve using JQuery/Javascript?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I get you right. Is something like this what you want?

```
$("#grid").on("click", ".k-button", function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    var dataItem = grid.dataItem(tr);

    var nextDataItem = grid.dataSource.at(($(tr).index() + 1));

    if (nextDataItem) {
        nextDataItem.Id = dataItem.Id;
        nextDataItem.Name = dataItem.Name;

        grid.refresh();
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h8j086aq/2/).

The event handler must be attached on the grid(`#grid`) and filtering by the button selector(`.k-button` in this case) because when the method `.refresh()` is called, it recreates the table content removing the old buttons and their events.